# Perform HTTP request through non-default gateway (CURL? WGET?)

Tags: windows, gateway, curl, wget, request

I have two ISPs /two routers on my LAN with Windows boxes. Switching default gateway (per PC) works fine, so I can choose my outgoing traffic from particular PC to be initiated from whichever ISP I want.

Is there any way to perform some specific HTTP request through ****non**-default gateway (while all other requests /browsing etc goes normally through default gateway); ideally with some cmd-line tool (like WGET or CURL)? I tried to search through their manuals, but couldn't find it. Alternatively, some solution in PHP would be fine too.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**No.**
Gateway selection is routing.
Routing is handled at the layer below HTTP.

The best you can do is specify a particular source address for your requests (which *may* send them through a different gateway, depending on your system's network configuration).

Refer to the manual for the software you're using (curl, wget, or other) to determine if this is possible, and what options to specify in order to do it.